# Printing the result I got from the two DateTimePicker

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, printing, datetimepicker

So I got my DateTimePicker done thanks to Mych! and there's this another problem our teacher wants us to do. After getting the result from the ranged using the two DateTimePicker, we need to print the result. Here is my code. There seems to be a problem with the If Then statement.

the error states:

> Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DataTable' and type 'BindingSource'.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    PrintDocument1.Print()

End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    If dt = DataGridView1.DataSource Then
        PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView1.DataSource, Font, Brushes.Black, 100, 100)

End Sub
```

Comment: Since you just created the DataTable in the previous line, it cant ever be the one used for the DS.  That has nothing to do with a DateTimePicker

Comment: @Plutonix so i don't need to make another DataTable?

Comment: I have no idea what a ` Button4` does, so I cant say

Comment: the Button4 is for the Print Preview @Plutonix